# Prove ord($\phi(g))|$ord$(g)$ using the first isomorphism theorem.

Tags: group-theory, vector-space-isomorphism

Let $\phi : G \to H $be a group homomorphism. Use the First Isomorphism Theorem to
show that if $g \in G$ has finite order, then ord($\phi(g))|$ord$(g)$.

My problem here is having to use the first isomorphism theorem, as I can prove this without. So far I have considered the order of $g$. Suppose $g^n = e_G$. Then (in the following $\overline{\phi}$ is the induced homomorphism $\overline{\phi}: G/(N=ker \phi) \to Im(\phi) \in H$. Then:

$(\overline{\phi}(gN))^n = (\phi(g))^n$
$ = \phi(g^n)$
$= \phi (e_G)$
$= e_H$

I think I should be able to use this to show that the number of cosets of $N$ divides $n$ but I'm really not sure to go with this. Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

If you are being asked to use the First Isomorphism Theorem what seems natural is to prove that the order of $gN$ in $G/N$ divides the order of $g$ in $G$ for the normal subgroup $N = \ker \phi$ (and you have the basic argument for this written already it just needs some tweaking) and then use that $\phi(G) \cong G/N$ along with the fact that an isomorphism preserves the order of any element it is applied to in order to finish the proof.